# Google Fonts appearing as Comic Sans?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm currently redesigning a website and am having trouble making the Google Font API display correctly.  I would like to display either "Short Stack" or "Permanent Marker", but both appear as a comic sans looking font...  Can anyone help?
[Here](https://www.toontowninfinite.com/revamp/steve) is the website.

Comment: I can't see any Comic Sans

Comment: Btw, it's very difficult to read the text, it's very small and the font makes it quite difficult

Comment: No Comic Sans on my end

Answer (score 1):

It block the stylesheet and shows a message.

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://www.toontowninfinite.com/inc/pages/home.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

Use secure HTTP in https://www.toontowninfinite.com/inc/pages/home.php

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are loading the page over https but the google fonts are coming from http (which is therefore considered to be an insecure connection and being blocked).  See the image below:

[image]

Change the google fonts to load over https and you should be good to go.